# Like system: Looping forms unique id, getting these id's with jQuery/Javascript to post Individually

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, variables

I'm just messing arround with simple PHP and Java by building my own Like system IP based.

Tryed looking for a solution, but no luck so far.

HTML generated forms in a while loop in php EOT obviously with every form unique id's. There are 25 forms with a Like button present. These forms are within a Bootstrap Modal. So because it is in a Modal, I do not want it to refresh the page and reset my Show More list. There for I'm trying to get all forms to be able to submit a Like by id by item using javascript. Code below.

Any suggestions or different approaches?

HTML - PHP While loop (forms within Modals):

```
<p id="result{$itemID}"></p>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" 
    action="{$postLike}"
    id="myform{$itemID}"
    name="{$itemID}"
    method="post">

    <input type="hidden" 
       name="itemids" 
       value="{$itemID}">

    <input type="hidden" 
       name="ips" 
       value="{$ips}">

    <button id="submit-btn{$itemID}" 
       class="btn btn-{$optionLikeColor}" {$optionLikeDisabled}>

           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up glyphr" 
               aria-hidden="true">
           </span> {$optionILikeText} {$likes}

    </button>

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

   require 'init.php'; 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['itemids'])){

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$itemsid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['itemids']);
$itemsip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SElECT * FROM likes WHERE itemID='$itemsid' AND ip='$itemsip'")) {

    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($row_cnt > 0){
            echo 'You\'ve have already liked this item.';
    } else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO likes (itemID, ip) VALUES ('$itemsid', '$itemsip')";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            echo 'Thank you!';      
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong, try again later!';  
        }


    }   

}

} else {

     echo 'Something went wrong, try again later!';

}

     mysqli_close($link);   

?>
```

Javascript working, but only for the first form:
So i'm guessing I need to pass the form / id variable into: $('#myform'), $('#insert'), $('#myform :input') and $('#result')

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
     return false;
});

$('#insert').click(function(){
   $.post( 
     $('#myform').attr('action'),
     $('#myform :input').serializeArray(),
     function(result){
       $('#result').html(result);
     }
   );
 });
```

Javascript concept not working obviously:P Suggestions?

```
   $("[id^='myform']").submit(function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('name');
        return false;
   });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#submit-btn'+ID,function(){
           $.post( 
             $('#myform'+ID).attr('action'),
             $('#myform${ID} :input').serializeArray(),
             function(result){ $('#result'+ID).html(result); }
             );
         });
     });
```

Comment: You need to work this down to a readable size. Be terse.  If you make us do research to answer the question, it will not get answered.

Answer (score 0):

Give all your forms the same class, or have some way to uniquely select those forms.  You don't need unique ids for all those elements.

Then:

```
$(".myFormClass").on("submit", function () {
  var $f = $(this); // the form that got submitted
  $.post( 
    $f.attr('action'),
    $f.find('input').serializeArray(),
    function(result){
      // not sure where you wanted the result.  
      // The point is that you should select it relative to the form $f that you already know.
      $f.find('span').html(result);
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm! Thanks!

```
   $('.myFormClass').submit(function(){
       return false;
   });

   $('.myFormClass').click(function() {
      var $f = $(this);
      $.post( 
         $f.attr('action'),
         $f.find('input').serializeArray(),
         function(result){
           $f.find('#submit-btn').remove(),
           $f.find('#result').html(result);
         }
       );
    });
```